# Add a new column with server name to the file using Ansible

Tags: csv, ansible

I have 4 files inside a folder /tmp/test namely serverA.csv (1,2,3), serverB.csv (4,5,6),serverC.csv (7,8,9),serverD.csv(10,11,12).
I have merged all these files using assemble module.

```
 - name: assemble files
    assemble:
     src: /tmp/test/
     dest: /tmp/logrotate/test.csv
```

Now the files are merged and new file test.csv has the merged contents.

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

What I need is, I need to add one more column in the beginning with the name of the server. the name is present in the filename.
Expected output.

```
serverA,1,2,3
serverB,4,5,6
serverC,7,8,9
serverD,10,11,12
```

Can anyone please provide any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are local to the ansible system, you can use an additional task before your  `assemble files`.

```
- name: prepend filename in every line
  replace:
    path: '{{ item }}'
    regexp: '^(.+)$'
    replace: '{{ item | basename | regex_replace("\.csv") }},\1'
  with_fileglob:
    - '/tmp/test/*'
```

When your files are on the remote system you have to use `find` instead of the `with_fileglob` before your task.

```
- name: find files
  find:
    path: '/tmp/test'
  register: result

- name: prepend filename in every line
  replace:
    path: '{{ item.path }}'
    regexp: '^(.+)$'
    replace: '{{ item.path | basename | regex_replace("\.csv") }},\1'
  loop: '{{ result.files }}'
```

Comment: Thank you, partially it worked, but it appends as serverA.csv,1,2,3. How can I remove the csv

Comment: Added a `regex_replace` to the answer.

Comment: It worked with replace: '{{ (item | basename|splitext)[0] }},\1'

Comment: This worked for linux, can you please suggest how to make this work for windows. replace is not working.

Comment: I guess you mean the second solution. There you have to use the [win_find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_find_module.html) module. It should be a no-brainer to fix it.

Comment: win_find is fine. But I tried using the replace module for windows and I get "msg": "winrm send_input failed; \nstdout: Unable to initialize device PRN\r\n\nstderr ANSIBALLZ_WRAPPER : The term 'ANSIBALLZ_WRAPPER' is not recognized as the name \r\nof a cmdlet,

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/208 I've no windows so I can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, every other tasks works in windows, only this module shows error. No problem.